# Database parent-child connection problmen

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ado.net, dataadapter

I have the following code

```
 Imports System.Data


 Public Class ReservationList

Private Sub GuestListToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GuestListToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Show the registration table

    GuestListForm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub HighriseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles HighriseToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' Shows the About Box
    highriseAboutBox.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' Terminates program
    highriseAboutBox.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub NewReservationToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewReservationToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' Restarts the program
    NewReservationForm.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    ' terminates program

    highriseAboutBox.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ReservationList_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CottagesDataSet.Guests' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.GuestsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CottagesDataSet.Guests)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CottagesDataSet.Reservations' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ReservationsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CottagesDataSet.Reservations)

End Sub

Private Sub Last_NameLabel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub


Private Sub Last_NameComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Last_NameComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

And when I run (debug) the program I get this

[image]

I am trying to setup a parent-child relation to show as shown below:

[image]

and this is the .xsd relation I have

[image]

SO that's all I have that I can show you. Any idea why am I getting this error? Everything seems to check on another database that I have setup the same way. I also followed a book tutorial and didnt miss anything. I'm close to just dump the whole idea but I would like to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 'Failed to Enable Constraints' error occurs when you have some form of database schema error.

To fix them:

1. Make sure your primary keys disallow null values, and that you haven't stored any nulls in there yet.
2. Make sure your 'relation' columns (Last Name, Guest)  are non-null, and that you haven't stored any nulls in there yet.
3. If you changed the length of the strings that Last Name, Guest can store, after adding data, you might hit the issue encountered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/27aec612-5ca4-41ba-80d6-0204893fdcd1/